# Is it possible to extend a component handler adding values?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following existing component:

```
<Existing value={val} onEvent={() => //no args} />
```

Problem is that the already defined onEvent callback does not provide the internal value of this element, which I would need.
So my idea would be to define a wrapper to it and, doing so, provide an onEvent(value) function.

Would this be possible?